# Error: A required parameter (locales) was not provided as a string in generateStaticParams for /[locales]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, parameter-passing, next.js13

I am trying to generate some static parameters for my Next.js 13 application using generateStaticParams, but I keep getting the following error:

"Error: A required parameter (locales) was not provided as a string in generateStaticParams for /[locales]"

Here is the relevant code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NextIntlClientProvider } from 'next-intl/client';
import { notFound } from 'next/navigation';

export function generateStaticParams(): { params: { locale: string } }[] {
    return [{ params: { locale: 'en' } }, { params: { locale: 'de' } }];
}

export default async function LocaleLayout({
    children,
    params: { locale },
}: {
    children: React.ReactNode;
    params: { locale: string };
}) {
    if (typeof locale !== 'string') {
        return notFound();
    }

    let messages;
    try {
        messages = (await import(`@/messages/${locale}.json`)).default;
    } catch (e) {
        return notFound();
    }

    return (
        <html lang={locale}>
            <body>
                <NextIntlClientProvider locale={locale} messages={messages}>
                    {children}
                </NextIntlClientProvider>
            </body>
        </html>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameters must match exactly. In this case your folder is named `locales` (plural) and your params return `locale` (singular).

```
export function generateStaticParams(): { params: { locales: string } }[] {
    return [{ params: { locales: 'en' } }, { params: { locales: 'de' } }];
}
```